# Time Complexity of While with function call of another class

Tags: java, time-complexity, ontology

What is the time complexity of this loop? The complexity of while loop with iterator is O(n) but since it has a function call as well to some other class. That function has one for loop only to read the list and if/else conditions. I am confused whether the complexity stays in O(n) or it will increase? because for loop consist of the n number of objects get from while so if i consider this only then for loop complexity is O(m) and m+n = n . But i am not sure whether this makes sense or not.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String queryString  = "" +
        "SELECT ?a WHERE {\n" +
        " ?a ?b ?c1 ;\n" +
        " ?e ?b ?c2 .\n" +
        "}";
    final Query query = QueryFactory.create( queryString );
    System.out.println( "== before ==\n"+query );
    ElementWalker.walk( query.getQueryPattern(), 
            new ElementVisitorBase() {
                @Override
                public void visit(ElementPathBlock el) {
                    ListIterator<TriplePath> it = el.getPattern().iterator();
                    while ( it.hasNext() ) {
                        final TriplePath tp = it.next();
                        AnotherClass ac = new AnotherClass();
                        ac.AnotherClassfunction(tp);
                        }
                    }
                }
    });
```

AnotherClass

```
   final static Set<Node> objects = new HashSet<Node>();
   static void AnotherClassFunction(TriplePath tp,)
   {
       Node Object  = tp.getObject();  
       Node Subject = tp.getSubject();      
       objects.add(tp.getObject());
       for(Node o: objects) {
           if(Subject.matches(o)) {
           print ....
    }
    }
    }
```

Thankyou!

Comment: It depends on the complexity of the other function.

Comment: Note that the code you're showing is iterating over the patterns declared in the query, not the results of running this SPARQL query. Unless the query is really complex or the operations you want to carry out on it require significant work, the complexity of the query patterns is likely to be a minuscule fraction of the cost of iterating through the results (the two patterns in this query will match every triple in the ontology, even if the second pattern might be dropped because unused to get the results - ?a is not constrained by it).

Comment: @lgnazio if i understood it correctly, so you are saying the complexity will may be in O(n^c)/ polynomial depending on the complexity of query? I am working on simple query patterns (for now assertions only) and no Join, filters etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't enough information to calculate the time complexity. It depends on whether the constructor `AnotherClass()` depends on any relevant parameters (e.g. global variables or other inputs), and on the behaviour of `AnotherClassfunction()`. But even if the body of the while loop was completely empty, the complexity wouldn't necessarily be `O(count(it))`. That depends on the implementation of the iterator.

For instance, it may well be that the cost of `AnotherClassfunction(tp)` depends on the size of `tp`. In that case the time complexity would not just depend on the length of `it`, but also on the size of the *contents* of `it`, so it may even be a multivariate function.

---

#### Update based on comments:

Assuming that the cost of `AnotherClassFunction` is indepedendent of the length `n` of `it` and only dependent on the size of its input argument `tp`, and assuming that all elements `tp` of `it` have the same size `m`, and assuming that iterating over `it` is O(n), and assuming that the time complexity of `AnotherClassFunction` is given by the function `g`, the total complexity of the loop is a function with two arguments that is in `O(n*g(m))`.

Comment: I have update the question with AnotherClassFunction .. size of the tp is not fixed, as it depends on the query size. "it" has (node, path, node) reading from querystring. is it multivariate function?

Comment: Yes, it seems to depend on lots of other functions, `getObject`, `getSubject`, `matches`, etc. And the code you pasted doesn't compile.

Comment: So, roughly what could be the time complexity of  above multivariate function?  as i have less knowledge about it.

Comment: @fairyjee I've updated the answer - you see, there are lots of assumptions...

Comment: This assumption is close to what i am doing. elements tp of it have the same size. This makes sense. Thankyou.